# Multiple Use case diagrams for a single project

Tags: uml

can I make multiple use case diagrams for a single project?
I wanted to show the whole activity in abstract and then get in to details for each use case in a different use case diagram. Is it a good idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it can be.  It all depends on how effective overall the diagrams are communicating the design.  My recommendation would be to try a first pass, and then solicit feedback on the level of detail from your audience.  You may find that in some cases you over-specified, while under-specifying in others.  There's no hard and fast rule.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm a student and trying to build a web project. That's where I was in doubt. Thanks once again.

Comment: Same advice works for a student... if you have the opportunity to show a draft to your TA or professor during office hours, for instance.  Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question because today in many tools you can not create multiple views of a single project using usecase diagrams.
This is a tool limitation therefore the best is to swap to another tool :-)